# Adding objects via DbContext duplicates related objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an object, I will call it Thing, that has a many-to-one relationship with another object, I will call it Person. How can I add Thing using DbContext without duplicating the associated Person. Thing has a foreign key to Person called PersonID.

```
public class Thing
{
  public long ID { get; set; }
  public long PersonID { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
  public long ID { get; set; }
}
```

I tried this:

```
context.Things.Add(newThing);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I also tried to do this:

```
Person person = new Person() { ID = newThing.PersonID };
context.Persons.Attach(person);
context.Things.Add(newThing);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Saying how you create `newThing` and populate its properties would likely make it much easier to answer the question.

Comment: How does it matter. For example, Thing newThing = new Thing() { PersonID = 1 }. What currently happens is EF will create another Person in the database with identical properties to the Person with ID=1 (of course the ID is incremented since it is the PK).

Comment: The whole context matters because what you are saying is not correct in the general case. If you just set the FK property and leave the navigation property `null` (you have a navigation property, right?) you don't get duplicated records. You have a special situation which causes this behaviour and I'm just asking for more context to get any idea what could be the reason.

Comment: @Slauma's comment above helped me out: It reminded me that I had set the navigation property on one of my objects which was causing all sorts of problems when I tried to re-attach it later on.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly but try:

```
context.Entry(Person).State = System.Data.EntityState.Unchanged;
```

This tells EF that the entity is unchanged and hence will not attempt to save it.